# Determine the value of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given $f: \mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function which expressed as
$f(z) = u(x) + iv(y)$
for every complex numbers $z = x + iy$. If $f(20)= 17$ and $f(17)=20$, then the value of $f(2017) =..... $

I have some doubt here. First, does $f(20)$ here means that the domain of function is $z = 20$ (which means that $x = 20$), hence $u(20)$ will be expressed as a result? 
This is an analytic function, so it should be known that it satisfies
and

$\dfrac{\partial u} {\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial v} {\partial y}$

and

$\dfrac{\partial u} {\partial y} = - \dfrac{\partial v} {\partial x}$

but to be honest,  I can't relate this to calculate $f(2017)$. Please help.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : If $f$ is analytic, $\operatorname{Re}f$ only depends on $\operatorname{Re}z$, and $\operatorname{Im}f$ only depends on $\operatorname{Im}z$, then I suspect it must be the case that $f(z) = az+b$ for some real constant $a$ and complex constant $b$

Comment: @MPW I missed the bit about $u(x,y)=u(x)$ and $v=v(y)$...

Comment: Could you give me more hint? I still don't catch up this

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $f$ is analytic function, so it satisfy Cauchy-Riemann Equation: $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$.

We know that $u$ only depends on $x$ and $v$ only depends on $y$. So, $u_x = v_y$ holds only if $u$ and $v$ is a linear functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If a function that depends only on $x$ is equal to a function that depends only on $y$ then both functions must be constant. Apply that to $\dfrac{\partial u} {\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial v} {\partial y}$...

Comment: How is that? Help.